# VS c# NetLink - pictureBox - MathCommand

Tags: .netlink

Has anyone experiance or a running example how to use within VS C# the NetLink.UI pictureBox to plot graphics, especially using the pictureBox - "MathCommand"

I use the code example below which throw a System.FormatException - wrong input character format

```
IKernelLink mathKernelLink = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink();
MathKernel mathKernel = new MathKernel();

pictureBox2.Link = mathKernelLink;
mathKernel.GraphicsHeight = pictureBox2.Height;
mathKernel.GraphicsWidth = pictureBox2.Width;

pictureBox2.PictureType = "Automatic";

try { pictureBox2.MathCommand = "Plot[x, {x,0,1}]";} 
catch ( FormatException e )
{ Console.WriteLine(e); }

if (mathKernel.Graphics.Length > 0)
pictureBox2.Image = mathKernel.Graphics[0];
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/ref/net/Wolfram.NETLink.UI.MathPictureBox.html): "To have the `MathPictureBox` display the result of a computation, set the `MathCommand` property to a string of *Mathematica* code (for example, `Plot[x, {x,0,1}]`)." Did it not work as described? Some other common problems are described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/ref/net/Wolfram.NETLink.UI.MathPictureBox.PictureType.html).

Comment: Thanks Oleksandr, I've just added a part of my code example which gives a FormatException ?

Comment: Ok, it works in case if "pictureBox2.Link = mathKernel.Link" are set.